# To get count of null values in the dataset

Tags: python, dataframe, null, duplicates, data-analysis

The requirement is, we need to check for duplicate values in a dataset and returns the counts of duplicated values are returned as a integer.

I have written this code but getting the below error:

```
def check_duplicates():
    ds = pd.read_csv("Hospital_patients_datasets.csv")
    # Method to check for duplicate rows in the DataFrame.
    # Returns: The number of duplicated rows found in the DataFrame.
    ds=ds.duplicated().count()
    return ds
```

> > Running Test case
> > ------------- Test Case Failed -------------
> > your output do not match the expected output:
> > ---------------------------------------------
> > Your Updated results:
> > 110527

```
Expected Output: 
0
```

Need actual count of duplicated values in the dataset.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Hi  B.h.1999! Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: are you wanting to get the count of nulls or the count of duplicates? Also, duplicate rows, duplicate values in columns, or duplicates across the whole dataframe?

Comment: duplicated() returns a boolean series, you can use count(Ture) on it, to get the number of duplicates

Comment: As True and False are equivalent to 1 and 0, you can get the count from the boolean series produced by `duplicated()` by using `dupes = ds.duplicated().sum()`

Answer (score 0):

You can count duplicates in pandas DataFrame by using DataFrame.pivot_table() function. This function counts the number of duplicate entries in a single column, multiple columns, and count duplicates when having NaN values in the DataFrame.

```
# Get count duplicates single column
ds.pivot_table(index = ['column_name'], aggfunc ='size')

# Get count duplicates multiple columns
ds.pivot_table(index = ['Column_1_name', 'Column_2_name'], aggfunc ='size')
```

Comment: Yeah thank you!! It worked for me!! i used ** ds = pd.read_csv("Hospital_patients_datasets.csv")
    # Method to check for duplicate rows in the DataFrame.
    # Returns: The number of duplicated rows found in the DataFrame.
    dup=ds.duplicated().sum()
    return dup**